# fresh vuejs GET http://192.168.1.102:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1608719207155 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Error

Tags: vue.js, websocket

Hi i build a new vuejs project with "npm create test" and serve that with "npm run serve"

And the result was this

[image]

But when I go to the desired address in "http://localhost:8080/" I get these errors in the console:

[image]

I researched this topic and the way I was suggested was to edit the config file and add this section

```
devServer: {
host: "localhost"
```

}

And this is my whole config file

[image]

But my problems persisted

I'm new in vuejs and i hopeful that you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a WebSocket problem, rather than Vue JS problem. Your application seems to assume that WebSockets are supported, but you did not install a support for them.

Comment: @LajosArpad Can you tell me what WebSockets is and how can I install it or make the program useless?

Comment: WebSockets are duplex web channels that support continuous information flow both from the server to the browser and from the browser to the server. They differ from the well-known HTTP protocol, since the latter is supporting a request-response communication, requests issued from the browser and received and responded to by the server. WebSockets are very useful for chat apps and gaming. I have provided some useful information about them in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your project attempts to use WebSockets via [socketjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client).

You will need to run

```
npm install sockjs
```

see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs

You will also need to have a **sockhost**, see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

Comment: npm not installed that Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socketjs - Not found

Comment: npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socketjs - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'socketjs@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-23T11_11_59_136Z-debug.log

Comment: @ali you are right, it was a typo in my answer. Edited it.

Comment: It is installed but my problem still persists

Comment: GET http://192.168.1.102:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1608722608245 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: @ali do you have a sockhost setting?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversockhost

Comment: I'm going crazy and I don't want to learn it anymore. If this package is so necessary, then why not install the program beforehand !!! I went crazy: (((

Comment: @ali in your project is necessary, but in many other cases it is not. I suggest to take a deep breath and revisit the problem after an hour or so. It usually helps.

Comment: thank you for your help but my project is a fresh project and i changed nothing in that but i got this error. i build many projects again and again and again But I still get these errors. But the educational video I follow does not have these errors at all

Comment: @ali then the educational error has some dependencies which you need to sort out before you follow the steps.

Comment: Thanks again. My nerves are more relaxed now. I will try again

Comment: I answered to my question. you can read that. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

1. create a fill named "vue.config.js" in main root.
2. add this scripts to the created fill:

   ```
   module.exports = {
   devServer: {
       host: 'localhost',
       hot: true,
       disableHostCheck: true,
       https: false
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's just due to a change of network, I think that if you restart the server or reconnect to original network it will dissapear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).